# Link not giving any output with 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to add a NavBar to the app.js file I have in react.
When I load the page the Route files are loading but the Link files set in NavBar aren't appearing.

This is the NavBar page

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => ( 
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/article">Article</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/article-list">Article List</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
)

export default NavBar;
```

Then below is the app.js file

```
import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';
import AboutPage from './Pages/AboutPage';
import ArticlesList from './Pages/ArticlesList';
import ArticlePage from './Pages/ArticlePage';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <div className="App">
        <NavBar />
        <div id="page-body">
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />}/>
          <Route path="/article-list" element={<ArticlesList />} />
          <Route path="/article" element={<ArticlePage />} />
      </div>
    </div>
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am keeping NavBar out of the pages folder
I'm stumped as to what it could be

Just incase the react-router-dom version I have in my *package.json* file is:

```
    "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.6",
```

index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: did you add a BrowserRouter?

Comment: yes BrowserRouter is in the index.js file

Comment: You basically want to show your navbar component in every route? Then you will have to wrap your navbar compnent in each route components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your navbar should be outside of your Routes tag in app.js, and then inside your navbar file, wrap everything around a  tag.

App.js should look like this:

```
import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';
import AboutPage from './Pages/AboutPage';
import ArticlesList from './Pages/ArticlesList';
import ArticlePage from './Pages/ArticlePage';
import NavBar from './NavBar';
import {Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
   <div>
    <NavBar />
    <Routes>
      <div className="App">
        
        <div id="page-body">
          <Route path="/" element={<Homepage />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />}/>
          <Route path="/article-list" element={<ArticlesList />} />
          <Route path="/article" element={<ArticlePage />} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Additionally, your nav component should look something like this:

```
   import React from 'react';
import { Link, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavBar = () => ( 
        <nav>
          <Routes>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/article">Article</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/article-list">Article List</Link>
                </li>
            </ul>
          </Routes>
        </nav>
)

export default NavBar;
```

You might also be running into a problem with the fact that you are wrapping around your App component with a  but i am not 100% sure on this one.

Comment: why import BrowserRouter if not using it in App.js?

Comment: @DavidGrosh because thats how it looks in their file. Its not needed, but I don't want to break anything. Once they remove it, they'll get the unused import message and realize on their own most likely. Feel free to edit my answer if you think I am missing something

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. Switch isn't supported in 'react-router-dom' version 6 'Switch' has been replaced with 'Routes'
When I try adding Routes in to the NavBar.js it is still not appearing

Comment: @robocop Oh, I see. My apologies. Maybe try checking this out? https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v6.0.0-beta.6

I think your navbar should be outside of your Routes tag in app.js, and then inside your navbar file, wrap everything around a <Routes></Routes> tag. I'll update my answer so you see what I am talking about.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, with your help I managed to figure it out.
It was as simple as my NavBar tag needed to be outside of <Routes> in app.js file.
If you try add Router or switch in the NavBar file you get an error.
I'm going to edit your answer with the correct format and mark it as correct. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: @robocop perfect! Glad I could help. Yes, please make sure to update it and mark it as resolved once done.